# Overclocked PC boots only after second attempt

Tags: boot, overclocking

I've overclocked my PC by increasing the system bus frequency from 200 to 333(266 has the same issue). Everything works fine except for booting.

When I press the power button, the PC starts up but reboots after only a second. After that it boots and works fine. Note that this only happens when I take the power cable out from the wall outlet. If I shutdown and then press the power button without unplugging the cable, the PC will boot fine from the first attempt.

I think that this may be a motherboard or power supply problem. Any suggestions?

Specifications:

- Intel Pentium E5200 dual-core
- Gigabyte GA-EP45-DS3L iP45 Socket 775 motherboard
- Kingston 4GB DDR2 RAM
- MSI R4850 HD GPU
- Zalman 600W power supply

Note that I'm making all of these changes in the BIOS. On the second attempt the BIOS is not resetting any of the settings - I know this because when it does reset the settings to the defaults it gives me a red message box saying that the settings were reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the motherboard. It didn't like the overclock.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making these changes in the BIOS?  It sounds like it is resetting settings when it reboots the second time around.  Does everything work ok normally at stock speeds?  You may have one part that does not like any sort of increase.  As always, with overclocking, stability can quickly be an issue.

Comment: Yes, in BIOS. Yes, at stock it works normally